# Android で常に画面いっぱいの文字サイズになるようにするにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Tags: android

機種に関わらず、スマホを縦にしても横にしても、文字の長さが画面いっぱいの文字サイズになるようにしたいです。どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

普通のTextViewです。

試したこと

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Start"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
```

画面の真ん中＆画面いっぱいいっぱいに表示したいのですが左上に小さく表示されてしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

1. `maxLines="1"` を指定する
2. `autoSizeMaxTestSize` に十分に大きなサイズを指定する（デフォルトのサイズは小さめのため）
3. 垂直方向は `gravity="center_vertical"` で TextView 内部でセンタリングする

**main_activity.xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="300sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hello!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: プレビューのスクリーンショット]